# Replace nested -> operator with . and * operators in C

Tags: c, pointers, struct, linked-list

Basically, my question could be summarized as "What is the equivalent to `a->b->c->d` with only `.`, `*` and `()` in C ?"

I'm exercising myself with creating a linked list in C to reproduce some of the behavior of Python lists and have a better understanding of the language. I have a basic structure to control my list

```
typedef struct _list
{
    Element* first;
    Element* last;
    int length;
    int* test_for_more_fun;
} Liste;
```

Then declare a null pointer in my main() `Liste* liste=NULL;`, and send his address to be able to modify what it's pointing on `init(&liste);`.

Then `init()` allocates the memory

```
void init(Liste** _liste)
{
    *_liste=(Liste*)malloc(sizeof(Liste));
    (**_liste).test_for_more_fun=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Then I would have like to access the fields first, last and length, I discovered to way of doing so

```
    (*_liste)->first=NULL;
    _liste[0]->last=NULL;
```

But, let's assume that first and last were also pointers of pointers, I'm not sure that this tricks would still works, so I asked myself: How could I do without `->`? I browsed the web without answer, *The C programming language* book page 118 sayed that

> The  parentheses  are  necessary  in  (*pp).x  because  the  precedence  of  the  structure  member  operator .  is  higher  then  *.  The  expression  *pp.x  means  *(pp.x),  which  is  illegal  here  because x is not a pointer.

So I tried `(*_liste).(*first)`, as `()` operator have the same priority than `->` I sought it would work but didn't, and `*(*_liste).first`, but again doesn't work. Can anyone explain me why this 2 ways don't work, and what is the correct way to proceed ?

Best regards

Comment: `Liste* liste=NULL;` is not a void pointer

Answer (score 2):

`(*_liste).(*first)` doesn't work because `.(*first)` is not a valid syntax in C.

`*(*_liste).first` doesn't work because `.` operator has higher precedence than `*` operator and it tries to read a member of `*_liste`, which is a pointer `Liste*` and don't have any member.

`A->B` means `(*A).B`, so `(*_liste)->first` can be written as `(*(*_liste)).first`. You can remove the inner parenthesis and write as `(**_liste).first`.

This can also be said that `_liste` is a pointer to pointer to `Liste`, so you should dereference two times to get the structure `Liste`.

Comment: Ok thanks, I see my mystake. But let's assume that I have an `int* test` in `Liste`, as `.(*test)` is not valid, how could I access it ? I could declare an `int* value = (**_liste).test;` and then works with value, but isn't there nicer way to do ?

Comment: `*(**_liste).test`?